# General Maxwell equations (moving media)

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames, maxwell-equations, lorentz-symmetry

This is something I vaguely remember seeing in a textbook (which was/is written in Romanian), but right now I couldn't find (I was initially hoping here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations, but no).

In the integral form of Maxwell's equations, it is assumed that the boundaries enclosing the charges/currents are stationary, i.e. it makes sense to put the total time derivative inside the double/triple integral into a partial one of the fields.

This, obviously doesn't work if the boundary is moving in space with a velocity vector $\vec v$ in an IRF. So how are the equations modified and how is the differential form changed? (with "transport terms", I presume).

Comment: The integral equations given by Wikipedia do in fact for moving boundaries, though this is not immediately obvious.

Comment: Putting $\Sigma (t)$ and $V(t)$ doesn't simply do it. That total differentiation has to act on these.

Comment: Yes, I know, and it turns out that if you combine the time dependence of the surfaces with the Lorentz force equation, everything works out to give the integral forms. Most EM books have a derivation of this, at least for Faraday's law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the people interested in my question, there is an answer in the whole chapter 9 of Panofsky, W., Phillips, M. - *Classical Electricity and Magnetism* (1962, ---+) which one can look for at his/her nearest science library.